# Shred document meta tags

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

I've found a handful of meta tags related to text editors:
[newlines](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/newlines) (and its synonym: [newline](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/newline)), [linebreaks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linebreaks), [bullets](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bullets)

I think none of them should exist.

And a related tag which also seems to be not necessary: [sorting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sorting)

Comment: title is a little too clever. I totally do not get it. Also, newline and newlines are synonyms so its essentially one tag

Comment: Totally agree with the first paragraph,  And [bullets] should be migrated to the ammunition site.  :-)  [Sorting] is a little different; mixed thoughts on that one.  Yes, it's meta, but it's a function tag for a basic function, like "printing".  Some kinds of sorting tasks aren't trivial, so answering how to do them can require more specialized knowledge.  It also may attract or filter answerers.  That one is probably worth cleaning up what is just decoration and then seeing if there's anything left that justifies having a tag.  I wouldn't nuke that one so fast.

Comment: BTW, I didn't think your title was that obtuse, but here's an alternative for now (from my years in Washington, DC).

Answer (score 1):

[sorting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sorting) is worth keeping IMO. It is useful for searching SU in conjunction with any of the Excel tags like with this example search phrase:

```
[sorting] [microsoft-excel]
```

The [sorting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sorting) tag can save SU users a lot of time. The search phrase `[microsoft-Excel] sorting` returned 1,489 results, while the tag specific search phrase `[microsoft-Excel] [sorting]` returned 104 results.

Replying to Robotnik's comment, I think if the [sorting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sorting) tag is deleted it will eventually come back anyway. The [sorting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sorting) tag is not used exclusively for tagging questions about documents and Excel.

Comment: do you think searching for  "[microsoft-Excel] [sorting]" will give better results than "[microsoft-Excel] sorting"?

Comment: Would it instead be worth disambiguating the [sorting] tag to be [microsoft-excel-sorting] so it is only used for this purpose?